# numerical integration for N datapoints

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I understand why [Simpson's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) is better than the trapezoidal rule for 3 datapoints (because under the assumption that the function is smooth, a parabolic approximation is going to be better than a piecewise linear approximation).

But suppose I had a given number N of measurements of f(x) at equally spaced intervals h where N is fairly large compared to the 3 datapoints for Simpson's Rule. Say N=61, for example.

Why is

S = h/3[f(x_0) + 4f(x_1) + 2f(x_2) + 4f(x_3) + 2f(x_4) + ... + 2f(x_56) + 4f(x_57) + 2f(x_58) + 4f(x_59) + f(x_60)]

a better approximation than

S = h [f(x_0) + f(x_1) + f(x_2) + ... + f(x_58) + f(x_59) + f(x_60)]

? I don't understand why you would weight one function datapoint with greater
importance than any other.

Is there either an intuitive or an analytical approach to understand this?

Comment: That endpoints should be given less weight is intuitively reasonable.

Comment: Well, I understand that part when N is small (I guess it's kind of like windowing functions in FFTs), but not when N is large.

Comment: There is a small discussion of this on page 134 of [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) where they show it is an artifact of how we derive these rules and give an alternative with equal weights through the interval.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern about the oscillating weights of Simpson's Rule (and other higher-order Newton-Cotes formulae) has merit.  I really am not aware of any significance attached to the weights.  In fact, the weights can have a detrimental influence by providing more significance to certain sample points than others, especially if some of those sample points are noisy.

I like Simpson's rule and have used it often, but if at all possible I stick with a simple trapezoidal scheme.  In fact, an even better scheme is [Romberg integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romberg%27s_method), which computes a sequence of approximations and applies a convergence accelerant (i.e. Richardson's extrapolation) to whittle down the error.

Comment: Huh, never heard of Romberg integration before, thanks... What if h is fixed (i.e. velocity measurements made once every N milliseconds) rather than something that can be increased adaptively?

Comment: That's OK, see the recurrence used.  You apply a trapezoidal rule once and apply an extrapolation to simulate a higher-order approximation.